# App crashes, try to upload image in landscape mode, swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape

Am new to swift. My App is in Landscape mode for iPad, I want to upload image in UIImageView in landscape mode. When i try to upload image the App change to portrait mode and got crashed. In Objective-c i have saw category for override UIImagePickerController and UIViewController

For UIImagePickerController

```
#import "UIImagePickerController+OrientationFix.h"

@implementation UIImagePickerController (OrientationFix)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
@end
```

For UIViewController

```
#import "UIViewController+OrientationFix.h"
@implementation UIViewController (OrientationFix)
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
@end
```

But in swift i cant do this, It shows error as shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not available. If anybody can help me.

My Code

```
@IBAction func PhotoClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    if( controllerAvailable()){
        let imageController = UIImagePickerController()
        imageController.editing = false
        imageController.delegate = self

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "get a picture from", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
        let libButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert) -> Void in
            imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            self.presentViewController(imageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
            let cameraButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert) -> Void in
                println("Take Photo")
                imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
                self.presentViewController(imageController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            alert.addAction(cameraButton)
        } else {
            println("Camera not available")

        }
        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (alert) -> Void in
            println("Cancel Pressed")
        }

        alert.addAction(libButton)
        alert.addAction(cancelButton)

        if let popoverController = alert.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = sender as UIView
            popoverController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
        }
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    else {
        var actionSheet:UIActionSheet
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
            actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Select a picture", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: nil,otherButtonTitles:"Select photo from library", "Take a picture")
        } else {
            actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "select a picture", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: nil,otherButtonTitles:"Select photo from library")
        }
        actionSheet.delegate = self
        actionSheet.showInView(self.view)
    }

}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, nil)
    imgProfile.image = image;

}

func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    println("Title : \(actionSheet.buttonTitleAtIndex(buttonIndex))")
    println("Button Index : \(buttonIndex)")
    let imageController = UIImagePickerController()
    imageController.editing = false
    imageController.delegate = self
    if( buttonIndex == 1){
        imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    } else if(buttonIndex == 2){
        imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    } else {

    }
    self.presentViewController(imageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func controllerAvailable() -> Bool {
    if let gotModernAlert: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Crash Message

```
2015-07-17 00:09:31.007 Stenteq[777:17782] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Give us the crash message you have. And you should paste your Swift code.

Comment: @Pierre I have updated my Question with My code and Crash message. please go through it. Do the Favour